# How to create a sample HelloWorld front end module in OTRS 5

Tags: perl, otrs

Creating sample module HelloWorld in OTRs

This is my directory structure

[image]

This is my HelloWorld. Spom related code

```
    <File Permission="otrs" Location="Kernel/Output/HTML/Templates/Standard/AgentHelloWorld.tt"></File>
    <File Permission="otrs" Location="Kernel/System/HelloWorld.pm"></File>
    <File Permission="otrs" Location="Kernel/Config/Files/HelloWorld.xml"></File>
    <File Permission="otrs" Location="Kernel/Modules/AgentHelloWorld.pm"></File>
```

I've created the package OPM, uploaded it and installed it, but it doesn't show HelloWorld。

I'm a new HelloWorld module based on the OTRs 7.0 developer's manual。

How do I need to show this list

Comment: Did you import HelloWorld.xml into the current config? If not, you could try "bin/otrs.Console.pl Maint::Config::Rebuild".

Comment: I have installed the package，I try "bin/otrs.Console.pl Dev::Package::Build and /bin/otrs.Console.pl Admin::Package::Install"  The package is installed, but the page is not displayed

Answer (score -1):

Just google manual for version 5. You can't use 7th manual. And there can be syntax error in one of exmaple pm files. You had to fix broken "plain old documentation" markup